# Powershell Error when read from json : Property 'dateFormat' value 'YYYY-MM-DD' is not acceptable

Tags: json, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I'm running a powershell(version 5) script that uses json templates to build streamAnalytics job in an Azure IOT-HUB account.
The streamAnalytics json file defines a storage blob as output, with these properties:

```
 "outputs":  [
{
    "Name":  "iotstreamingoutput",
    "Properties":  {
    "DataSource":  {
    "Properties":  {
      "Container":  "outputblob",
      "PathPattern":  "{date}/{time}",
      "DateFormat":  "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "TimeFormat":  "HH",
      "StorageAccounts":  [
          {
              "AccountKey":  "xxxxx"
              "AccountName":  "accountName"
          }
                      ]
     },
   "Type":  "Microsoft.Storage/Blob"
},
"Serialization":  {
      "Properties":  {
                         "Encoding":  "UTF8",
                         "Format":  "Array"
                     },
      "Type":  "Json"
              }
   }
 }
]
```

This PowerShell script run the command:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment 
  -ResourceGroupName $IotHubResourceGroupName 
  -TemplateFile templateStreamAnalytics.json 
  -TemplateParameterFile parametersStreamAnalytics.json
```

But when I run the script it returns this error:

```
*'StreamAnalyticsJob' failed with message '{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "**The JSON provided in the request body is invalid. Property 'dateFormat' value 'YYYY-MM-DD' is not
acceptable.",**
  "details": {
    "code": "400"
```

Can someone please help me understand why this error occures?

Comment: What/where is the script?

Comment: Are you missing a double quote at the end of `"{Date}/{Time},`

Comment: @MickyBalladelli Turns out your answer was most probably right. I guess you can undelete it.

Comment: @Tomalak Your answer was spot on given how the question was constructed at the beginning

Comment: It probably still is, in a way, but the OP uses some Azure cmdlet that does it exactly like this, so there is little to be done about the approach.

Answer (score 4):

You have defined minutes instead of months, try with "yyyy-MM-dd".

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings